# Issue with passing data using delegate while instantiating a storyboard with identifier

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I did go through various posts from other users which seemed to deal with similar issue of delegate but frankly I couldn't pull enough information from them to handle my current issue..:) My issue goes something like this..

I am having a tableview loaded with a few tableview cells. And clicking on a certain edit icon on these cells takes me to another viewcontroller. The tableview cell also has a certain `productName` on it which is a label.

Now the issue is when I click on the edit button, I want to take this `productName` to the other viewcontroller so that I can display it in the back button of the navigation bar. In the tableviewcell class I have made a delegate like so...

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func editBtnTapped(cell: ProductsTableViewCell)
}
```

And on tapping the edit button, like so...

```
   @IBAction func editBtnTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.editBtnTapped(cell: self)
        }
    }
```

In the tableviewcontroller class where this tableviewcell is loaded, I have called the `editBtnTapped` method like so...

```
func editBtnTapped(cell: ProductsTableViewCell) {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProductsIdentifier")
    let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Here I am presenting another viewcontroller and it is to this viewcontroller that I have to pass my `productName` that I have in my 
tableviewcell class. And this I am not able to achieve..:(

Comment: What is your issue?

Comment: the label that I have in my tableviewcell...that I want to pass to the viewcontroller that I have loaded with an identifier...

Comment: @ Usman Javed Also, that label I have not shown above. But I have declared it my tableviewcell class...

Comment: If outlet to your label is drawn in the cell class. Then you can simply access it by cell.lableName.text and get the product name and pass it to your view controller.

Comment: @Ishika No..no...I want to pass that label to another viewcontroller and not access it in the viewcontroller where the tableviewcell is loaded...

Comment: So where is the error, why are you not able to pass it. Please specify where is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a variable like `var titleFromCell = ""` in your destination ViewController (the one with id : editProductsIdentifier)

Then replace this line :

```
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProductsIdentifier")
```

by those 2 lines :

```
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProductsIdentifier") as! //The Custom Class of this View controller
controller.titleFromCell = cell.productName.text
```

Then you will be able to display it in the navigation bar

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `tableSelectedRowIndex` in `func editBtnTapped()` instead of passing cell class reference. Through this you can easily achieve your goal. You can do like this

Declare protocol in tableViewCell class like this

```
protocol MyCellDelegate {
    func editBtnTapped(SelectedIndex : Int)
}
```

also create an IBOutlet of edit button in tableViewCell class

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnEdit: UIButton!
```

and create its action

```
@IBAction func editBtnTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let _ = delegate {
            delegate?.editBtnTapped(SelectedIndex: sender.tag)
        }
    }
```

then set the editbtton tag value to `indexPath.row` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cellIdentifier = "customCell"
    var cell : CustomCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier) as! CustomCell?
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomCell", owner: nil, options: nil)?[0] as? CustomCell
    }

    cell.btnEdit.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell!
}

    func editBtnTapped(SelectedIndex : Int) {

        let productName = // get name of product like you display in cellForRowAtIndexPath

        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "editProductsIdentifier")
        controller.productName = // Pass your product name
        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
        self.present(navController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

Please let me know if you found anything difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Have given an upvote...:) Accepted the above answer since it was given first and also worked...